# How to determine which version of tor a node is running

Tags: node

https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html can see which version of Tor a node is running.

How do you remotely determine that?

E.g. with ssh I can simply `telnet server 22` and the server will tell me which version of SSH it is running. Can I do something similar with a tor node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the relay's server descriptor and read the [`platform` line](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n483). You can access this at the `http://1.2.3.4/tor/server/authority` URL for a given relay's IP address if they have their `DirPort` enabled on port 80. You can also download a [network consensus document](https://metrics.torproject.org/collector/recent/relay-descriptors/consensuses/) and find a relay's platform string in there. The [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) library can make this easier to script, and would also allow you download the status document over a relay/OR connection if the relay doesn't have its `DirPort` enabled.

If you plan on doing this a lot, you should download these documents from the [Tor Metrics](https://metrics.torproject.org) website to avoid putting extra strain on the relays.